# jQuery Mobile and Phonegap

Tags: jquery, xcode, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile

Hi so I've been looking into developing a mobile application and have heard about phonegap which will allow me to use native languages like html5 css and javascript. From what I've read I should use jQuery mobile so I'll be able to do events like slide, tap ect. When it comes to coding the application I noticed that jQuery has a data attribute for a `page` container, so would I code my entire application in 1 document and just us the data attribute for `page` for each of my pages, or would I code it like I would normally would with a website and have several different pages linking to them? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different architecture just like you mentioned, one page architecture and multipage architecture. From my experience, people prefer one page architecture more as it's easier and maybe faster (since you just need to load all the javascript and css once).

But beware that since all your "pages" are now in a single pages, there's a risk you will be reaching the dom maximum size limit. But that's relatively easy to fix.

Comment: Awesome thanks, yeah that's what I was thinking, thanks for your time!